# Invalid use of 'this' in non-member

Tags: c++, this, qpainter

I have a problem - discussed a lot previously, but all solutions I saw doesn't work here. 
What is wrong in this code?

`main.cpp:8:19: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <math.h>
class QPainter;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,3));

  int n=8;
  for (int i=0;i<n;++i){
    qreal fAngle=2*3.14*i/n;
    qreal x = 50 + cos(fAngle)*40;
    qreal y = 50 + sin(fAngle)*40;
    painter.drawPoint(QPointF(x,y));
  }


  return app.exec();    
}
```

Comment: You will need at least one widget in your program if you want anything shown on the screen.  Neither `QApplication` nor `QPainter` is a widget.

Comment: Your problem is that you haven't taken any time whatsoever to try to learn C++.  Instead you are just copying and pasting code snippets from random places on the internet and expecting them to work out of context.

Comment: This is from the book Shlee Qt 4.5. "Professional programming on C++",  chapter 18

Answer (score 4):

In the function "main" you are using the reserved keyword "this" which means "address of the current object". main is a function and not a member of any class or object that would have a "this" variable. I know nothing about qt but 5 seconds with google tells me that "QPainter" wants the address of a QPaintDevice.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#QPainter

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about QPainter painter(this); you are using the this pointer in main. The this pointer is for member functions of an object. Your main function doesn't have a this pointer to use.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt you need to create a window (inheriting from `QWidget`) before you can see anything on the screen. You then create a `QPainter` object inside the `paintEvent` method of your window and there you will have the proper `this` to pass to `QPainter` constructor.

You're highly encouraged to follow some tutorial. Qt is fantastic, but it's huge and it's not a library, but a framework (like most other GUIs).

Your code must be structured in a quite specific way.

Answer (score 1):

You just tried to copy some code without understanding what was going on.

It looks like you saw a code like this :

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
 
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
 
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        //create a QPainter and pass a pointer to the device.
        //A paint device can be a QWidget, a QPixmap or a QImage
        QPainter painter(this);   // <- Look at this !!
        //               ^^^^ Allowed    

        // ...
    }

signals:

public slots:
 
};
 
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
 
    MyWidget myWidget;
    myWidget.show();
 
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here you can see that in the function paintEvent of the `class` `MyWidget` we use the `this` pointer. We can because we use it in a non-static member of the class. Here `this` is of type `MyWidget*`.

Look at the standard :

> **9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]**
>
> In the **body of a non-static member function**, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*.

So you cannot use the `this` pointer inside the `main` function, this is no sense.

And other thing, like it is said in the comment inside the code, you just have to pass a pointer to a device to the `QPainter` constructor. It can be a `QWidget`, a `QPixmap` or a `QImage`.

Maybe you should read this for a beginning : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/